# Open and Closed Set intervals

Tags: general-topology

What is an example of an open set $A_1$ in the reals which contains the interval (1,2) but so that $A_1$ is not itself an interval.  Find another $A_1$ except this time $A_1$ is a closed set containing (1,2) but is not itself an interval.

I think that the open set $A_1$ would be something like (4,5)U(1,2) because now it isn't an interval but it is still an open interval I think.

However, I'm not sure about the second one.  Would a possible answer be something like [4,5]U[1,2].  I know that it isn't an interval, and I believe it is closed.

Do these $A_{1}$'s work?

Comment: You are correct on both.

Comment: In your first example, $A_1$ isn't an *open interval* (which you wrote - oops) but it's *open*. Both of your examples are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they actually both work! Remember that in a metric space, in this case, $\Bbb{R}$, any finite union of open sets is open, and any finite union of closed sets is closed!

Comment: Oh, I forgot about those rules.  But it does make complete sense.  Thanks for the info.